# How can i use regex pattern the first from the end to have the last sentence in python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have the netx text:

```
"TITULO: Albedo SUBTITULO Y PARRAFO: ===Trees===
Because forests generally have a low albedo, (the majority of the ultraviolet and [[visible spectrum]] is absorbed through [[photosynthesis]])
"

"TITULO: Albedo SUBTITULO Y PARRAFO: ==Human activities==
Human activities (e.g., deforestation, farming, and urbanization) change the albedo of various areas around 
"TITULO: Abraham Lincoln SUBTITULO Y PARRAFO: ===U.S. House of Representatives, 1847–1849===
[[File:Abraham Lincoln by Nicholas Shepherd, 1846-crop.jpg|thumb|upright|alt=Middle
```

I want to create a dataframe using regex in python:

```
Tile                   Head                          TEXT
Albedo                 Trees                         Because forests generally have a low  ...([[photosynthesis]])
Albedo                 Human activities              Human activities (e.g., de...areas around 
Abraham Lincoln        U.S. House of..1849           [[File:Abraham Lincoln by... line Whig,
```

I have this code, the first and the second colums it works but the third column i don´t know 
How can i get from last == or === or ==== forward ? That is to say.

Because forests generally have a low albedo, (the majority of the ultraviolet and [[visible spectrum]] is absorbed through [[photosynthesis]])

Human activities (e.g., deforestation, farming, and urbanization) change the albedo of various areas around

[[File:Abraham Lincoln by Nicholas Shepherd, 1846-crop.jpg|thumb|upright|alt=Middle

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

pandas_dict = defaultdict(list)

with open("datos_titulos.csv", "r") as f:
    for line in f:


        pat = r"TITULO: (.*) SUBTITULO Y PARRAFO: ==(.*?)==|rTITULO: (.*) SUBTITULO Y PARRAFO: ===(.*?)==="
        pat2 = r"TITULO: (.*) SUBTITULO Y PARRAFO: ==(.*?)==$|rTITULO: (.*) SUBTITULO Y PARRAFO: ===(.*?)===$"

        if re.search(pat, line) :

            pandas_dict["title"].append(re.search(pat, line).group(1))
            pandas_dict["head"].append(re.search(pat, line).group(2))
        if re.search(pat2, line) :

            pandas_dict["text"].append(re.search(pat2, line).group(2))
df = pd.DataFrame(pandas_dict)
```

Comment: In your input file, are the Texts on the same line as the corresponding Title and Subtitle?

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

pandas_dict = defaultdict(list)

regx_title = r"TITULO: (.*) SUBTITULO"
regx_head = r"={2,}(.*?)={2,}"
regx_text = r"^(?!\")(.+)"

regex_list = [regx_title, regx_head, regx_text]

with open("datos_titulos.csv", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        for i, regx in enumerate(regex_list):
            r = re.findall(regx, line)
            if r:
                pandas_dict[i].append(r[0])

df = pd.DataFrame(pandas_dict)
df = df.rename(columns={0:"Title", 1:"Head", 2:"TEXT"})

with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', 25):
    print(df)
```

Details

- `"TITULO: (.*) SUBTITULO"`

  - `(.*)` - Capturing group: any 0 or more chars other than line break chars
- `={2,}(.*?)={2,}`

  - `={2,}` - two or more character `=` literally
  - `(.*?)` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars (as few times as possible)
  - `={2,}` - two or more character `=` literally
- `^(?!\")(.+)`

  - `^` - start of a line
  - `(?!` - Negative Lookahead (assert that the regex below does not match)

    - `\"` - matches the character `"` literally
  - `)` - close Negative Lookahead
  - `(.+)` - Capturing group: any 1 or more chars other than line break chars

Moreover, that last regex captures any line that doesn't begin with `"`, so make sure that
the `text` field you want is the only thing starting in the line except from `"`. From your sample text
this works well as can be seen in the output provided, but if for any reason your `text` field is
on the same line you can use this regex:

```
TITULO: (.*) SUBTITULO|={2,}(.*?)={2,}|(?<===)(.+)
```

With this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

regx = r"TITULO: (.*) SUBTITULO|={2,}(.*?)={2,}|(?<===)(.+)"

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
with open("datos_titulos_inline.csv", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        r = re.findall(regx, line)
        if r:
            df1 = df1.append([[r[0][0], r[1][1], r[2][2]]])

df1 = df1.rename(columns={0: "Title", 1: "Head", 2: "TEXT"}).reset_index(drop=True)

with pd.option_context('display.max_colwidth', 25):
    print(df1)
```

See the regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/3nqIMQ/3) for inline `text` field.

Output dataframe:

```
             Title                      Head                      TEXT
0           Albedo                     Trees   Because forests gene...
1           Albedo          Human activities   Human activities (e....
2  Abraham Lincoln  U.S. House of Represe...   [[File:Abraham Linco...
```